# How expensive is substring in a query? Should i have the values in a table instead?

Tags: mysql, substring

So, after weeks of research, I finally decide it on my db model for my fan site gallery:

1. I have images and each image comes in different sizes that are in a 2 level file system structure.
2. Each image has up to 5 different sizes (small, thumb, medium, large, xlarge). The sizes are basically a suffix that I add at the end of the image name.
3. The first level directory is the last integer from the right of the image name, and the second level directory is the second integer from the right…
4. I have a constant variable in php that defines the root of the image main folder:

   ```
   define('IMAGE_PATH', '…/images/')
   ```

   So, an image path could look like this:

   ```
   …/images/6/7/3346642.4565676.jpg
   ```

   and the small size of that image:

   ```
   …/images/6/7/3346642.4565676_s.jpg
   ```

   …the large size:

   ```
   …/images/6/7/3346642.4565676_l.jpg
   ```

   and so on…

The tables look like this:

```
image (image_id, title, caption, file_dir, file_name, file_ext, update_date, upload_date)
image_size (size_id, name, suffix)
image_data (image_id, size_id, width, height)
```

Here’s the question. I don’t need the `file_dir` and even the `file_ext` since I can get those using PHP or in the query (using `substring` and `concat`) But, I’ve read that using substring in a query is expensive… I figure that if I already have those in table, it’s faster and no need to use php or functions inside the query… 
What do you think? Is it too much to have those values in a table… to redundant?

I could just have the filename (i.e: `3346642.4565676.jpg`) and let PHP or the query figure out the relative path from the image folder or I could have the file directory and the file extension separately in the table…

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question well since we don't have all the information about the way your code is set up.  But my advice would be not to worry too much about performance of concatenating strings.  Just set up whatever is most convenient for you, and makes since in terms of keeping the information organized in a clear and natural way, conceptually.  Later, if you find there is a performance problem, you can deal with it, but I doubt it will make much difference one way or the other whether you store full path names in sql or not.  I suspect you might want to be able to move all the images to another folder without having to update all the rows in oyur database?